# Return month/years between two dates in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have records with a Start Date and an End Date in a single table.

I need to pivot this up such that I have years on the X, and months on the Y ...

```
         1     2     3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
2000   123   123   123  123  123  123  123  123  123   123   123   123
2001   123   123   123  123  123  123  123  123  123   123   123   123
2002   123   123   123  123  123  123  123  123  123   123   123   123
2003   123   123   123  123  123  123  123  123  123   123   123   123
```

... with a count of items that may be regarded as being "active" on account that in the position in the matrix (year/month) the month/date falls within the records' Start/End Date.

I've managed a PIVOT based on a single date for another task, but this is essentially a PIVOT on a date-range, including every date in between the start/end dates!

Is there something I don't know about in T-SQL that could enable this?

Comment: This problem may seem difficult to you because to you it is a complex one: you know how to PIVOT, but you do not know how to pivot *this*, and I think it's because you do not know *what* to pivot. You could start with a ‘normal’ GROUP BY query and return the results in a form of `Year, Month, Count`, just to make sure you can achieve the necessary aggregation *at all*, before moving on to pivoting the results.

Answer (score 4):

using the sales table in the classic PUBS database you could get the number of orders by year, month with the following:  Perhaps from there you could derive what you're looking for.

```
select y, [1] as January,
            [2] as February, 
            [3] as March,
            [4] as April, 
            [5] as May, 
            [6] as June, 
            [7] as July, 
            [8] as August, 
            [9] as September, 
            [10] as October, 
            [11] as November, 
[12] as December 
from  (select ord_num, 
        DATEPART(year,ord_date)as y,
        DATEPART(month, ord_date) as m from sales) as p
 pivot (count(ord_num) for m in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) as pvt
 order by pvt.y
```

Comment: This seems to be what I already have, and it works, but pivoting on a single date. For this particular scenario, I need to identify the dates within a range. So for a given date range: Nov 2001 - Mar 2002, the pivot should count for each of the 5 months in the 2001 Nov,Dec and 2002 Jan,Feb,Mar "cells". Sorry if this wasn't clear (or I have misunderstood you)

Answer (score 2):

when I have to convert date ranges to year/month values, I iterate through the months to determine which points are within that range, then store it in another table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ssis_sa_yr] 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @yr int
    declare @mo int
    declare @i int
    declare @moStart datetime
    declare @nextMoStart datetime

    delete from serviceagreement_year

    set @i = 1
    while @i < 6
    begin
        set @yr =  year(getdate()) - @i
        set @mo = 1
        while @mo < 13
        begin
            set @moStart =  cast(cast(@mo as char(2)) + '/1/' + cast(@yr as char(4)) as datetime)
            set @nextMoStart =  dateadd(m,1,@mostart)

            insert into serviceagreement_year
            SELECT     SANumber, @yr AS yr, @mo as mo
            FROM         dbo.ServiceAgreement sa ...        
            WHERE     (DateFrom < @nextMoStart) AND (DateTo >= @moStart)
            set @mo = @mo + 1
        end
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, Beth. Your answer gave me sufficient inspiration to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured it out. It probably isn't pretty but a bit of time away and having read Beth's idea I had a spark.

I've come up with:

```
create procedure sp_MIS_mySP 
    @fromDate datetime=null,
    @toDate datetime=null,
    @debug int=0
as 

-- get overall date range
declare @firstDate datetime
declare @lastDate datetime

select top 1 @firstDate=Start from MIS_Policies where (@fromDate is null or Start>=@fromDate) order by Start
select top 1 @lastDate=End from MIS_Policies where (@toDate is null or End<=@toDate) order by End desc

if @debug=1
begin
    print 'Parameters:'
    if (@fromDate is null) print '   @fromDate=NULL' else print '   @fromDate='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@fromDate))+''''
    if (@toDate is null) print '   @toDate=NULL' else print '   @toDate='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@toDate))+''''
    print 'Evaluated:'
    print '   @firstDate='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@firstDate))+''''
    print '   @lastDate='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@lastDate))+''''
end

-- step through date range by month
--   inserting count of active contracts at that point
declare @dateTImePtr datetime
set @dateTImePtr=dateadd(d,-(datepart(d,@firstDate)-1),@firstDate)

declare @startOfMonthPtr datetime
declare @endOfMonthPtr datetime

create table #yearMonthActiveBreakdown (
    [year] int,
    [month] int,
    [count] int)

while @dateTImePtr<=@lastDate
begin
    set @startOfMonthPtr=@dateTImePtr
    set @endOfMonthPtr=DATEADD(m,1,@startOfMonthPtr)
    set @endOfMonthPtr=DATEADD(d,-1,@endOfMonthPtr)

    if @debug=1
    begin
        print '@dateTimePtr='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@dateTimePtr))+''' (@startOfMonthPtr='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@startofMonthPtr))+''', @endOfMonthPtr='''+rtrim(convert(varchar,@endOfMonthPtr))+''')'
    end

    -- insert row for year/month aggregating by count of items
    insert into #yearMonthActiveBreakdown ([year],[month],[count]) 
        select year(@dateTImePtr),
            MONTH(@dateTImePtr),
            COUNT(ContractNumber) 
            from MIS_Policies 
            where 
                Start<=@endOfMonthPtr and End>=@startOfMonthPtr and Status in (0,3,4,5)     

    set @dateTImePtr=DATEADD(m,1,@dateTimePtr)

end

if @debug = 1
begin
    -- pre-pivot
    select * from #yearMonthActiveBreakdown
end

select [YEAR],[1] as [Exposure_1],[2] as [Exposure_2],[3] as [Exposure_3],[4] as [Exposure_4],[5] as [Exposure_5],[6] as [Exposure_6],[7] as [Exposure_7],[8] as [Exposure_8],[9] as [Exposure_9],[10] as [Exposure_10],[11] as [Exposure_11],[12] as [Exposure_12]
from (
select [Year],[Month],[Count]
from #yearMonthActiveBreakdown p
) as s
pivot (sum([Count])
for [Month] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) as pivoted

drop table #yearMonthActiveBreakdown
```

So I'm taking the overall date range and creating a loop, iterating through that loop per month. It seems to output what I need, but it's late and I can't really verify until I get back into the office. It's the iterative approach I was thinking I might be able to avoid, but, I guess not.

***Updated***

Updated to slightly more production quality code, including considerations highlighted by Andriy.

Comment: I thought Ralph Shillington was demonstrating the reverse, i.e. that the iterative approach *could* be avoided. On the other note, the `WHERE` condition of the `INSERT ... SELECT` in your loop seems to imply (in connection with the fact that you are truncating `@dateTimePtr` to months) that any range of `ServiceContractRiskStart`..`ServiceContractRiskEnd` always crosses or includes the first of a month. Is that so?

Comment: Thanks Andriy. Ralph's answer only works for a single fixed point in time, so you're right, that approach does not need an iterative approach. However, to get every data-point (months in this case) between two dates seems to require an iterative approach. I may be wrong, I'm learning T-SQL through this! 

With regards the 1st of the month factor, I'm aware of the necessity for the start period to be at the end of the first month. This is essentially pseudo code until I got back into work and smoothed it out. +1 for the spot, though!

Answer (score 0):

The following query presents a purely set-based approach. Basically, this is an attempt at translating your answer to a set-based solution.

```
;
WITH
  QueryPeriod AS (
    SELECT
      Start = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, MIN(Start)), 0),
      [End] = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, MAX([End])) + 1, 0))
    FROM MIS_Policies
    WHERE (@fromDate IS NULL OR Start >= @fromDate)
      AND (@toDate   IS NULL OR [End] >= @toDate  )
  ),
  Months AS (
    SELECT
      Start = DATEADD(M, v.number, p.Start),
      [End] = DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, v.number + 1, p.Start))
    FROM QueryPeriod p
      INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
        ON v.number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(M, p.Start, p.[End])
    WHERE v.type = 'P'
  ),
  Query AS (
    SELECT
      [Year]  = YEAR (m.Start),
      [Month] = MONTH(m.Start),
      ContractNumber
    FROM MIS_Policies p
      INNER JOIN Months m ON p.Start <= m.[End]
                         AND p.[End] >= m.Start
    WHERE Status IN (0, 3, 4, 5)
  ),
  Grouped AS (
    SELECT
      [Year],
      [Month],
      [Count] = COUNT(ContractNumber)
    FROM Query
    GROUP BY
      [Year],
      [Month]
  ),
  Pivoted AS (
    SELECT
      [Year],
      Exposure_1  = [1],
      Exposure_2  = [2],
      Exposure_3  = [3],
      Exposure_4  = [4],
      Exposure_5  = [5],
      Exposure_6  = [6],
      Exposure_7  = [7],
      Exposure_8  = [8],
      Exposure_9  = [9],
      Exposure_10 = [10],
      Exposure_11 = [11],
      Exposure_12 = [12]
    FROM Query
    PIVOT (
      COUNT(ContractNumber) FOR [Month] IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
      )
    ) p
  )
SELECT *
FROM Grouped /* Pivoted */
```

Here's a bit of explanation of what each part does:

- The `QueryPeriod` CTE returns a row representing the (actual) beginning and ending of the requested period, i.e. `Start` is the first of the month represented by either `@fromDate` or `MIN(MIS_Policies.Start)`, and similarly `[End]` is supposed to contain the last of the month that is either passed as `@toDate` or retrieved as `MAX(MIS_Policies.[End])`. I thought that was what you were doing in the beginning of your SP, and I hope I haven't erred too much there.
- The `Months` CTE builds the months table spanning the months from `QueryPeriod.Start` to `QueryPeriod.[End]` inclusive. The table will be used for filtering/collecting `ContractNumber`s whose periods start in, end in, are within, or cross the months specified. Like in your updated logic, each month is represented in the form of a date range, the `Start` & `[End]` columns.
- The `Query` CTE is, if I may say so, the heart of the entire query. This is where the base row set is obtained, the one upon which grouping (and pivoting) is later performed. The `WHERE` clause is borrowed directly from your answer.
- The `Grouped` CTE is there merely to show you how much (or how little) a GROUP BY query differs from a ‘corresponding’ PIVOT query. I think you can trace the resemblance without much difficulty. This is basically what I meant when I suggested you to first try to come up with a GROUP BY solution, because converting it then to a PIVOT solution should not be too difficult once you know the basics of the pivoting technique using the PIVOT syntax.
- The last part, `Pivoted`, almost entirely replicates the PIVOT query in your answer. I'd like to stress that this PIVOT subquery reads the rows directly from `Query`, not from `Grouped`, so the two last CTEs are sort of replacements of each other, and `Grouped`, when no longer needed, can just be removed. Don't forget to uncomment `Pivoted` in the main SELECT (and comment out `Grouped`) to actually see what it returns.